# Is it possible to use a custom class in place of std::pair in an STL map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, std-pair

Is this possible?

```
#include <map>

class Example {

  private:
  std::map<std::string, std::string, less<std::string>,
    std::allocator< CustomPair<std::string, std::string> > > myMap;
};
```

In the example above, CustomPair would be a template class holding a key and value. If this is possible, is it that simple or is there anything I should look out for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One can only speculate what your real intent is here, so I assume you already have a class that contains both key and value. In that case std::set with a custom comparison may be a better choice than a std::map.

You then need to provide a comparison that will only compare the key part of your class and the key part must be const (not change over time) as long as the object is in the set.
As mentioned in the comment the elements of a set are only accessable as consts, so if you want to change the value of a such element you need to const_cast the write access or declare the member mutable.

In another answer **iain** made another very good suggestion. If you rarely insert into the container and mostly access the container searching for elements then a sorted std::vector and std::binary_search are a very effective alternative to the set.

Comment: The main problem with this might be that set holds constant values in order to maintain the ordering, so the CustomPair would have to have the second member be mutable, and force the comparison to only use the first member.

Comment: @Greg Rogers Thanks, added the constness of the key part to the answer.

Comment: I don't know what the intent of the OP was, but his question was about passing CustomPair<...> as template parameter to std::allocator instead of pair<...>.  This does not answer the question.

Comment: @Ari allocators can not change the internal implementation of std::map, they can only change where and how the memory for std::map's internal data is allocated.

Answer (score 3):

I would be more likely to use std::set.

Answer (score 3):

I would either use a set as described by lothar or use an sorted `std::vector` as described in "Effective STL" chapter 23: "Consider replacing associative containers with sorted vectors".

The rational for this is that a `std::binary_search` of a sorted vector with a custom comparitor is nearly as fast and sometimes faster than a map lookup and iteration is much faster.  The insert operations are more expensive though (you have to call sort after each insert).  A lot of map use cases insert very infrequently though.

The vector would be more flexibility than the set.

I replaced a map of 2000 complex objects (indexed by int) with this approach, iteration and processing every object in the map went from 50 seconds to less than 5 on a server class system. There was no noticeable difference for map lookups times.

Comment: std::binary_search() just returns whether the specified value exists. Did you mean std::equal_range()?

Answer (score -2):

I think you can do it but will not get the desired effect, because the use of `std::allocator` will be done via `rebind<std::pair>`, thus overriding your selection of `CustomPair`.  In fact, it probably doesn't matter what type you put there, the STL functions will ignore it.  At least some of them will definitely do this, but I'm not sure all will.  Strictly speaking this is almost certainly implementation dependent.  I don't know what the standard says.

Comment: @Ari allocators can not change the internal implementation of STL containers, they can only change where and how the memory for the containers internal data is allocated.

Comment: Indeed, my answer says that you can do what the OP asked for literally, but you won't get the desired effect.  I also went on to explain how this is possible (compile okay, but doesn't do what you think).  What's the problem.